# Combine UPDATE and SELECT statement - adding blank space on the same column

Tags: sql

I want to do something like this but always getting error so code is not correct. I want to update 
the same column with blank space.

```
update table 
set (select line as line1 from  table where id='100')=line1+' ' 
where id='100'
```

Thanks

Comment: what is this query should to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `DB2` (assumed from your previous questions, works in `MySQL` too):

```
UPDATE  table
SET     line = CONCAT(line, ' ')
WHERE   id = '100'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update table 
set line=line+' ' 
where id=100
```

something like this?